# jQuery trigger returns deferred

Tags: jquery, plugins, triggers, deferred

I'm trying to trigger custom event, which will return deferred.

I use trigger inside plugin, so I can't just do `this.options.beforeOpen().done()`... because inside `beforeOpen()` at the client side `$(this)` will return options object in this case.

```
$me.trigger('beforeOpen').
                        done(function(){
                            me._open();
                        })
                        .fail(function(){
                            me.state = 'closed';
                            $me.trigger('ifNotOpened.' + me.name);
                            $me.trigger('ifOpenedOrNot.' + me.name);
                        })
```

Inside my custom event

```
$me.on( 'beforeOpen', function() {
                        var d = $.Deferred();
                        setTimeout(function(){ d.resolve() },1000);
                        return d.promise();
                    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized how to do it:

```
var deferred = me.options.beforeOpen.call( $me );
    deferred
        .done(function(){...})
        .fail(function(){...})
```

Hope that will help someone.